# every time I come back to a previous line in vs code all the tabs in that line disappear

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, tabs

I am using vs code with unity to make c# scripts and when I come back to a previous line that only contains tabs all of those tabs disappear, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: check the setting **Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible causes that I can thinking of right now to what you're seeing:

Check your settings for an "Editor: tab size". What I've seen is that tabs are sometimes replaced with spaces within the editor. Depending on what plugins you have installed, such as plugins that reformat your code, it may change the default behavior. I use a few different formatting plugins so the behavior I see may be different from your setup, but I do have some of them replace tabs with spaces, and it uses that tab size as the conversion key.

There is a settings for "Editor: Trim Auto Whitespace" that will remove excess whitespace.  If you don't have anything on the lines that only have tabs, that setting may remove all of those tabs.

Hope that gives you some ideas on what to search for within the settings.